# Facing error while adding/downloading solc by doing yarn add solc but throws error about node version

Tags: node.js, yarn-v2, solc

[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/7vRMv.jpg)[enter image description here](https://i.stack.imgur.com/rvrw6.jpg)[while doing 'yarn add solc' throws error expected node version differ then the version i have](https://i.stack.imgur.com/qMy6U.jpg)

error

error hawk@0.10.2: The engine "node" is incompatible with this module. Expected version "0.8.x". Got "21.7.1"
error Found incompatible module.

i try yarn add solc. it throws error that expected version is v0.8.x but i have the latest node version v21.7.1. now i don't know what to do. please help me.

Comment: [Please do not upload images of code/data/errors.](//meta.stackoverflow.com/q/285551)